# Remove unstaged files from merge

Tags: git, merge, unstage

i have two branches, one more updated than other one and I want to merge into the outdated one the updated but only the commits that don't cause conflicts.
When I do the merge and try to checkout the unstaged files it says 'warning: path "my file" is unmerged' and i want to merge anyways, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your branches `outdated` and `updated`. I'm assuming you want to do the merge of `updated` into `outdated` without merging the conflicted files but somehow *keeping* your `updated` branch's version of them. So:

1. Get on `outdated`. Attempt the merge of `updated`.
2. Git emits a list of conflicting files.
3. Write down their pathnames.
4. Abort the merge.
5. Get back on `updated`. Copy the conflicting files to a place of greater safety (outside this worktree).
6. Checkout, from `outdated`, the conflicting files, thus overwriting the conflicting files in `updated` with versions of those files that do not conflict because they are identical.
7. Get back on `outdated` and do the merge.
8. Get back on `updated` and copy the conflicting files back into the worktree.